# MKMapViewDelegate is nota called when inside a subclass of MKMapView

Tags: delegates, mkmapview, subclass, mkmapviewdelegate

I am quite new in Objective C, but learning fast. My project is quite complete and I have implemented as well classes than delegates etc etc.

I am using an MKMapView to display things on a map. I also need the user to click on Pins which will give back some informations, but I do want that the MKViewMap makes some estimations before sending info.

As such I have subclassed MKMapView, and I am using this class to display. But I don't get the delegates called. It worked normally when I was using MKViewMap in a standard way. Here is some code. The subclass has a delegate protocol, and this works perfectly

// .h file

```
#import < MapKit/MapKit.h >

@protocol MyMapViewDelegate < NSObject >

@required

- (void) ReturnAddressToHail:(NSString*) FullAddresse andNumber:(NSString*) FullNumber;
- (void) ReturnSelectedDriverHash:(NSString*) DriverHash;
@end


@interface MyMapViewClass : MKMapView < MKMapViewDelegate >

{

id < MyMapViewDelegate > delegate;

CLLocationCoordinate2D mapCenter;
NSDictionary *Info;
CLLocation * ClientNewLocation;

}

@property (retain) id delegate;
```

// .m file

```
#import "MyMapViewClass.h"
#import "NSObject+MapAnnotationHelper.h"

@implementation MyMapViewClass

@synthesize geoCoder;
@synthesize delegate;

self.delegate = self;


-(void) mapView:(MKMapView *) mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated

{

(void) self.updateAddress;
NSLog(@"regionchange delegate");

}
```

The latter is never called. Any ideas?

Comment: I found the solution. I had to replace
self.delegate=self;

with
super.delegate=self;

Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you have your reasons, but the docs state that you shouldn't subclass `MKMapView`, and instead use the delegate to change its behaviour. There may be an easier way to do whatever you're doing.

> Although you should not subclass the MKMapView class itself, you can get information about the map view’s behavior by providing a delegate object.